# exportar y usar variables en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente archivo donde estan almacenados los valores asignados a dos variables; mismos que exporto con `module.exports`

```
//archivo datos.js

const num1 = 12
const num2 = 22

module.exports = {
    uno: num1,
    dos: num2
}
```

Ahora bien en un archivo por separado recibo esos valores que deseo usar dentro de una función para poder sumarlos y retornar su valor

```
//archivo app.js

let op = require("./datos.js")

let numeroUno = op.uno
let numeroDos = op.dos

console.log(numeroUno + numeroDos)
```

> Si lo hago del modo anterior accediendo con la variable op y despues a
>   la clave deseada, puedo hacer la suma sin problemas

Sin embargo si paso esas variables dentro de una función obtengo un error de tipo `NaN`

```
//De este modo no me sale el ejercicio

let op = require("./datos.js")

let numeroUno = op.uno
let numeroDos = op.dos

function suma(numeroUno, numeroDos){
    return numeroUno + numeroDos
}

console.log(suma())
```

> El error en consola es NaN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La funcion espera dos parametros y no estas pasando ninguno.  Intentalo asi:

```js
let numeroUno = 1
let numeroDos = 2

function suma(numeroUno, numeroDos){
    return numeroUno + numeroDos
}

console.log(suma(numeroUno, numeroDos))
```

Comment: gracias @alanfcm ahorita marco tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas pasarle el valor a de las variables a la funcion `suma`

```
suma(numeroUno, numeroDos)
```

Aparte de ello si accedes de esta manera

```
let numeroUno = op.uno
```

Estas rompiendo el principio de encapsulacion, que deberia ser por medio de los setter y getters

```
function getNumeroUno(){
return numeroUno;
}
```